# Remote connection error on php only, not navicat/workbench on mysql 8 using php_pdo windows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-workbench

I know there are billions of questions for that same error  out there

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'ALEXPC' (using password: YES)

I myself even handle this error like hundred of times during the past 10 years.

But this case is weird : both navicat and mysql workbench can connect to this mysql 8 ( and browse things ) just fine. Just my php code (which worked well on mysql 5.7). Same user/password.

One more strange thing, my php machine name is capitalized in the error message after the first time:

```
 //    first  
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dev'@'alexpc' 
 // then  
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dev'@'ALEXPC'
```

And mysql "users and Previleges" tool says "Mysql only allows lowercase characters for hostnames, the account host will be updated accordingly".

P/s: I am using nginx-cgi on windows and php 7.3.4